# Specify the Node Resource Group Name for an Azure Container Apps Environment in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-container-apps

I want to host a container app on Azure and I'm using Bicep to define the deployment. When I deployed the app, I was surprised to find another resource group named `MC_{lots-of-random-text}_westeurope` where all the expensive stuff (kubernetes, public IPs) was stored.

I'm not happy with this outcome, I would much rather have everything in one resource group, but at least I learned that this is a [node resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks) and Azure does not want to give me container apps without one. But can I at least give a more useful name to the node resource group? The documentation says it should be `MC_myResourceGroup_myAKSCluster_eastus`, but in my case, the name is just random garbage.

I tried to specify a `infrastructureResourceGroup` for the container app environment, but that didn't work, I just got another random name.

```
resource containerAppEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2023-05-01' = {
  name: containerAppEnvName
  location: location
  properties: {
    infrastructureResourceGroup: 'actually-useful-name'
    appLogsConfiguration: ...
    vnetConfiguration: ...
  }
}
```

How can I specify a custom name for the node resource group in my bicep template? Or better yet, deploy a docker container without the need for a separate node resource group?

Comment: `infrastructureResourceGroup` should work with this api version

Comment: so, is this a bug? should I try one of the -preview versions?

Comment: is it consumption only or workload profile ? consumption only does not support changing the name of the resource group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli#workload-profiles-environment-2

Comment: Are you trying with workload profile or consumption only. @klamann

Comment: yeah, I'm using consumption only... that's quite the premium I'd have to pay just for the privilege to pick a non-random name. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 0):

> Specify the Node Resource Group Name for an Azure Container Apps Environment in Bicep:

According to the MS Doc, `infrastructureResourceGroup` property from [ManagedEnvironmentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.app/2023-05-01/managedenvironments?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#managedenvironmentproperties) of app managed environments resource will be used to provide name of a managed resource group created of the Managed Environment to host infrastructure resources.

Try with the latest Api version which is `2023-08-01-preview`. I tried same in my environment and was able to deploy it as expected.

```bash
resource containerAppEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  name: containerAppEnvName
  location: location 
  properties: {
    appLogsConfiguration: {
      destination: 'log-analytics'
      logAnalyticsConfiguration: {
        customerId: logAnalytics.properties.customerId
        sharedKey: logAnalytics.listKeys().primarySharedKey
      }
    }
    infrastructureResourceGroup: 'xxxx'
  }
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also control the resource group creation from where your cluster is deployed. Use resource group and location properties to achieve that.

[`Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

Comment: tried it with 2023-08-01-preview and set the infrastructureResourceGroup, still the same. The name is just random.

Comment: What is the bicep version you are using? @klamann